# EJB unit Test Case

Tags: ejb-3.1

Team,

We need to do EJB 3.1  Unit Test cases. For that we are analyzing  tools to do efficient testing. We are taking arquillian, cactus in consideration. Can anyone tell me which tool is suitable for our technology stack in performance wise. We are using JBOSS+Hibernate

Answer (score 4):

You might check out the [technique of using the Embedded Container](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/embedding_ejb_3_1_container) in EJB 3.1.

Comment: I've found that tricky because of the need to set up a database. Even embedded Derby seems troublesome.

Answer (score 3):

Testing EJBs is my daily challenge. The simple answer is don't. Here are some basic reasons why it's better to have unit tests than integrated tests: http://blog.thecodewhisperer.com/2010/10/16/integrated-tests-are-a-scam/

Nevertheless, if testing EJBs is really something you want and need I've committed few articles how to approach it (JBoss and Hibernate is my configuration as well). 
Sometimes OpenEJB is an overkill and simple mocking is enough - I suggest Mockito http://mockito.org and some examples I've written http://jakub.marchwicki.pl/posts/2011/05/06/the-art-of-testing-an-ejb-application-part-ii/

Answer (score 0):

Use an embedded container in your Maven setup, then mock-out any interfaces to the EJB system with either your own mock objects, or Mockito. That way you can just focus on testing the 'flesh' of the EJBs and nothing else.